# Android Tablet KML/KMZ App for polygons w/offline & GPS capabilities?

Tags: kml, gps, android, field-mapping, tablet

I am looking for an Android app which allows me to view and query polygons stored in KML and/or KMZ with a GPS point representing my location and offline capabilities. My KMZ files are being output from ArcGIS 10.2.2 representing some several thousand features (lakes, ponds, etc.). I would like to be able to view these features by navigating to them via GPS.

Previous poking around online has suggested that Backcountry Navigator (BCN) & Gaia GPS (Gaia) would be good places to start. I was able to load the large the large KML into BCN, but the polygons are serrated and the Object IDs are not always readable. Ideally, I could click on one of the features and look at the attributes. Gaia had issues loading such a large file, but the user interface is very agreeable.

Other posts on GIS StackExchange have suggested Locus. After downloading the free app, I found  that there were a number of issues with obtaining offline apps. For whatever reason, after trying a couple of WiFi connections, I was not able to download the tiles to my 2013 Nexus 7 (Android 4.4). Conversely, BCN & Gaia downloaded the offline maps with ease.

Does anyone have a recommendation? Bonus points if the app allows the overlay of large raster files (~200 km^2 with 1 m resolution).

Answer (score 1):

Try Orux maps. It has the capability to download tiles for offline use, load KML overlays and load raster for background imagery. Not sure though it has all the functionality you need in terms of KML attributes but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my work, I combine SpatiaLite and the JTS library to display large shapefiles(SpatiaLite r-tree) and so far so good!

My offline map base is OSM-Android or [RMaps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RMaps).

Sorry for my poor English.